# Take password form file from the correct username line

Tags: c#

I have a username|password file, where username is separated by a pipeline from the password and each line has such username/password combination

While knowing the username, I would like to be able to get the corresponding password

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\userPass.txt");
string username = "Johnny";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `ReadAllLines` or `ReadLines` instead, you will get an array of lines from the file that you can search, splitting each line on the `|` character. The first part of the split (at index `0`) will be the user name, and the second part (index '1') will be the password.

In the code below, we use `StartsWith` to find the first line that begins with the username and a "|" character, then return the password portion of that string. It will return `null` if the username is not found:

```
static string GetPassword(string userName, string filePath = @"C:\userPass.txt")
{
    if (userName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userName));

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find specified file", filePath);

    return File.ReadLines(filePath)
        .Where(fileLine => fileLine.StartsWith(userName + "|"))
        .Select(fileLine => fileLine.Split('|')[1])
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Note that this does a case-sensitive comparison on the username. If you want to allow case-insensitivity, you can use:

```
.Where(fileLine => fileLine.StartsWith(userName + "|", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

**Usage**

```
string username = "Johnny";
string password = GetPassword(username); 

// If the password is null at this point, then either it 
// wasn't set or the username was not found in the file
```

Comment: Thank you for this clean and simple solution but  I am getting "The method or operation is not implemented" when trying to run this code

Comment: you do need tip have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the code file